# Passing int array with unnamed pipes

Tags: c, pipe

I have to create a program that creates 4 children. the first child should only pass an array of ints (the array is passed on from arguments) to the next, second should increase all values by 20% and pass them on, third should increase them 30% and the fourth should print them all out. So far I managed to make this, but I don't fully understand pipes yet, or rather how to pass an array through them.

EDIT: figured most of it out, though now my program hangs sometimes and doesn't process the inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int kom_pipe[2];
int kom_pipe2[2];
int n,i;
double prices[argc-1];

pipe(kom_pipe);
pipe(kom_pipe2);

for(n = 1; n<argc; n++){//fill array
    prices[n-1] = strtol(argv[n],NULL, 10);
}

//write(kom_pipe[1],&prices,sizeof(int)*(argc-1));

for(n = 0; n<4; n++){
    switch(fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("error with fork");
        return -1;
        case 0:;
            double prices2[argc-1];         
            if(n==0){
                close(kom_pipe[1]);
                close(kom_pipe2[0]);
                //read(kom_pipe[0],&prices2,sizeof(int)*(argc-1));      
                write(kom_pipe2[1],&prices,sizeof(double)*(argc-1));
                /*for(i = 0; i<argc-1; i++){
                    printf("%.5f ",prices[i]);
                }
            printf("\n");*/


            }else if(n==1){
                close(kom_pipe[0]);
                close(kom_pipe2[1]);
                read(kom_pipe2[0],&prices2,sizeof(double)*(argc-1));        


                for(i = 0; i<argc-1; i++){
                    prices2[i]*=1.2;
                }
                write(kom_pipe[1],&prices2,sizeof(double)*(argc-1));


            }else if(n==2){

                close(kom_pipe2[0]);
                close(kom_pipe[1]);
                read(kom_pipe[0],&prices2,sizeof(double)*(argc-1)); 
                for(i = 0; i<argc-1; i++){
                    prices2[i]*=1.3;
                }
                write(kom_pipe2[1],&prices2,sizeof(double)*(argc-1));


            }else if(n==3){
                close(kom_pipe[0]);
                close(kom_pipe2[1]);
                read(kom_pipe2[0],&prices2,sizeof(double)*(argc-1));
                for(i = 0; i<argc-1; i++){
                    printf("%.5f ",prices2[i]);
                }
            printf("\n");
        }
    close(kom_pipe[0]);
    close(kom_pipe2[0]);
    close(kom_pipe[1]);
    close(kom_pipe2[1]);
    _exit(0);
    }
}

close(kom_pipe[0]);
close(kom_pipe2[0]);
sleep(1);
close(kom_pipe[1]);
close(kom_pipe2[1]);
for(n = 0; n<4; n++){
    wait();
}   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me, was a quick edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is subject to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). The children you create can execute in any order, and indeed in parallel. So if `n == 0` happens first, followed by `n == 3`, the input is written to `kom_pipe2` by the former, read from `kom_pipe2` by the latter, printed unchanged, and the other two subprocesses will hang because `n == 1` is waiting for an input that has already been claimed by someone else and `n == 2` depends on `n == 1`. Your writing and reading of the array is mostly fine, just don't use the same pipe for two different purposes.

This could still break in a rare condition when one of the `write`s would be interrupted in the middle and the `read` would not find the whole data. That's what the return value of `read` is for. You should ideally write a loop that tries to fill the buffer incrementally and only exits once the data has been received in full. In pipes with a few bytes of payload that's not going to be a problem, but it's a daily bread with IP sockets.

Note that your code does not provide any advantage over doing all the operations in a sequence. Even if you pass the initial array as a whole, the filters on the way can be parallelized better if they read the `double`s one by one. If this was an assignment that might be what was expected.

As side remarks,

- If you replace `_exit()` by `exit()` you don't need to close all the pipes, that's done for you. And you don't need to close them in the parent process in any case. Is there a specific reason not to use `exit()`?
- The `sleep()` at the end is entirely needless, and the arbitrary 1 second is not a sign of a good code. The `wait()` will take care for waiting for the subprocesses. (Also check its return value to watch for interruptions by other signals than `SIGCHLD`.)